# sbt deprecation warning <<= replaced with := results in no main class found

Tags: scala, sbt, deprecation-warning, mainclass

When using sbt 0.13.13. I could observe that when using `:=` no main class is found (but no deprecation warning is shown), and for `<<=` I get the warning, but the main class is found. What is wrong here?

```
run in Compile := Defaults.runTask(fullClasspath in Compile, mainClass in(Compile, run), runner in(Compile, run))
run in Compile <<= Defaults.runTask(fullClasspath in Compile, mainClass in(Compile, run), runner in(Compile, run))
```

Comment: `:=` and `<<=` have different types. You'll need to change the body but I am not sure exactly what changes are needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`run` is an `InputTask[Unit]` and the type of `runTask` is `Def.Initialize[InputTask[Unit]]` and the right side of `:=` needs to be a `Unit`.

What you did compiles because any value can be discarded in favor of a return value of type `Unit`, but it doesn't have the same semantics as before.

For input tasks, you need to "evaluate" the task:

```
run in Compile := Defaults.runTask(
  fullClasspath in Compile,
  mainClass.in(Compile, run),
  runner.in(Compile, run)).evaluated
```

Comment: "any value fits the Unit type", just to be pedantic, it's more that any value can be discarded and the unit value () can be inserted.